# Python spawning thread for one function

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to run one function concurrently from all the other code and this function do not return anything it just measure time and make sure some gpio pins are on/off so I don't need to join threads or anything I guess but I can't make it work. Main code is executing on some condition it calls `timeToRun` function this function make sure that certain GPIO pin or whatever is on for example 10 seconds and after that thread/process is killed without stopping main code.
In my mind it should look like that.

```
main code ----------------------------------------------------
                  \-------------------X
```

For now I got something like that but this in fact turn GPIO pin to LOW but never turn it back to HIGH

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import concurrent.futures


def initPins(pin):
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)


def clean():
    GPIO.cleanup()


initPins(26)

def timeToRun(timeToSpin):
    GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)
    initTime = time.perf_counter_ns()/1000000 # convert to ms
    while True:
        currentTime = time.perf_counter_ns()/1000000
        if currentTime - initTime >= timeToSpin:
            GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)
            print((currentTime - initTime) - timeToSpin)

user = [2000]


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.submit(timeToRun, user)



for i in range(0, 10):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.5)


clean()
```

I have tried with `ProcessPool` too but with that code stop and wait until time passes. Is this even possible to do as I think?
EDIT:
I didn't add this but function is working as expected the problem is when I try to multi-thread it.

SOLUTION:
I found the solution

```
import threading

class MyWorker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, timeToSpin):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.timeToSpin = timeToSpin
    def run(self):
        timeToRun(self.timeToSpin)

def timeToRun(timeToSpin):
    GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)
    initTime = time.perf_counter_ns()/1000000 # in ms
    while True:
        currentTime = time.perf_counter_ns()/1000000
        if currentTime - initTime >= timeToSpin:
            GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)
            break

user = 10000
thread1 = MyWorker(user)
thread1.start()
for i in range(0, 100):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I would say that is close enough time is a bit off sometimes but that was expected.

BETTER SOLUTION by JohanL:

```
import threading
def test():
    GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)

user = 10.0
GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)
timer = threading.Timer(user, test)
timer.start()
for i in range(0, 100):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: I think you should have a look at `threading.Timer(...)` It is perhaps a cleaner solution to your probem? I.e. you can have the main progam turn the pins high, and then set a timer to turn them low again after a certain time.

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you, that is something I looked for